# Wordpress accessing post_meta on save

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the value of a post_meta when the post is published. The problem is that all I can get is the post ID, but the post_meta must not yet be in the database when I make the query. I do not know to get this hook to fire after all of the post_meta for the post has been saved:

```
function get_some_meta($post) {

    $feat_img = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feat_img', true); // This has not yet been saved, so I can not retrieve it...

    // Do something with $feat_img...   

}

add_action('save_post', 'get_some_meta', 11, 1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69810/how-to-access-the-post-meta-of-a-post-that-has-just-been-published

Comment: The information on that page did not provide a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the post meta before or after the post is saved. However,  the post data is not available while word press is saving the post meta, which technically means its updating the post data, anyways.